# Firebase Flutter flavor does not work with Android Studio

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-flavors

When I run *flutter run --flavor dev -t lib/main_dev.dart*, I still have the data from my Firebase "prod" project instead of "dev".

1. With Android Studio, I have created two configurations :

> - main_dev.dart with dev build flavor
> - main_prod.dart with prod build flavor

2. build.gradle :

   flavorDimensions "default"
   productFlavors {
   dev {
   dimension "default"
   applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
   }
   prod {
   dimension "default"
   }
   }
3. Distinct google-services.json file in two different folders :

> - app/src/dev
> - app/src/prod

4. Distinct firebase_options.dart in two different folders :

> - lib/dev
> - lib/firebase/prod

5. Flutter clean

Comment: Android Studio merges resources from different flavor directories. Ensure that your `google-services.json` is not being overwritten during the build process. You can verify this by checking the merged `google-services.json` in the build output directory.

Comment: I do not find google-services.json in build output directory, where should i find it exactly ?

Comment: What should I do to avoid this merge ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link of firebase_options.dart was the one from prod instead of dev in main_dev.dart.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear your your problem. Because can't see detail of your project structure. As for me I build with flavor as below code and suppose this will help for you.

Firstly build two main entry file for prod and dev.

for **`PROD`** flavor

```dart
void main() async {
  FlavorConfig(
    flavor: Flavor.prod,
    flavorEnvironment: "Production",
    appTitle: "Production",
    flavorValues: FlavorValues(
      appId: "com.example.production",
      baseUrl: BASE_PRODUCTION_URL,
    ),
  );
  mainPrimary();
}
```

for **`DEV`** flavor

```dart
void main() async {
  FlavorConfig(
    flavor: Flavor.staging,
    flavorEnvironment: "Dev",
    appTitle: "Dev",
    flavorValues: FlavorValues(
      appId: "com.example.dev",
      baseUrl: BASE_STAGING_URL,
    ),
  );
  mainPrimary();
}
```

for **`main`** file, the entry of project

```dart
void mainPrimary() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

for **`FlavorConfig`** file,

```dart
class FlavorConfig {
  final Flavor flavor;
  final FlavorValues flavorValues;
  final String environment;
  final String appTitle;
  static FlavorConfig? _instance;

  factory FlavorConfig(
      {required Flavor flavor,
      required FlavorValues flavorValues,
      required String flavorEnvironment,
      required String appTitle,}) {
    _instance = FlavorConfig._internalConstructor(
      flavor: flavor,
      flavorValues: flavorValues,
      environment: flavorEnvironment,
      appTitle: appTitle,
    );
    return _instance!;
  }

  FlavorConfig._internalConstructor({
    required this.flavor,
    required this.flavorValues,
    required this.environment,
    required this.appTitle
  });

  static FlavorConfig? get instance => _instance;

  static bool _isStagingApp() => _instance?.flavorValues == Flavor.staging;

  static bool _isProdApp() => _instance?.flavorValues == Flavor.prod;
}

class FlavorValues {
  final String? appId;
  final String? baseUrl;
  final String? basicToken;

  FlavorValues({
    this.appId,
    this.baseUrl,
    this.basicToken,
  });
}

enum Flavor { prod, staging }
```

To change the data depend on flavor, use like that

```dart
child: GetMaterialApp(
        title: FlavorConfig.instance!.appTitle,
      ),
```

As native flavor configure in **`app/build.grade`** like that

```
    flavorDimensions "Sample App"

    productFlavors{
        staging{
            dimension "sampleApp"
            applicationId "com.example.staging"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        prod{
            dimension "sampleApp"
            applicationId "com.example.production"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }
```

To run project just type with below command

```
flutter run --flavor dev -t lib/main_dev.dart
```

You can set `google-services.json` for different flavor in by adding in **`DEV`** and **`PROD`** file.

If above instruction can't help you. You should double check the **appId** while building project in firebase.